# Vstest.console.exe can't find nunit tests

Tags: selenium, nunit, vstest.console.exe

I have VS 2017 and .net 4.6

On trying to run via cmd prompt using vstest.console:

```
vstest.console.exe bin\Release\Tests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
```

I am getting warning "No test is available in `/bin/Release/test.dll` Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."

So, I tried listing the tests but it doesn't show any tests.

```
vstest.console.exe bin\Release\Tests.dll /ListTests /UseVsixExtensions:true
```

Unit tests class file is as shown below.

```
[TestFixture]
public class class1
    {
    static void StartTest(string[] args)
    {

    }

 [Test] [Category("Regression_Test")]   
    public void TS1()
    {

    }
}
```

I tried googling for similar issue but didn't find anything that would work. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 8):

Have you actually installed the NUnit 3 test adapter as a vsix?

If you are using the more usual approach of installing via nuget, you need to tell `vstest.console.exe` where to find the adapter using the `/TestAdapterPath` option.

Comment: I've installed NUnit 3 Test Adapter via Nuget, does /TestAdapterPath need to point to the NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll? - I can't get this to work...

Answer (score 2):

Use this way:

```
"<full_path_of_exe>\vstest.console.exe" "<full_path_of_dll>\NUnitTestProject.dll" /TestAdapterPath:"<point_to_the_FOLDER_where_your_NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll_is>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Charlie already mentioned. Just install the nuget package in your project and everything ist fine!

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/

---

The old NUnit 3 Test Adapter extenion won't be supported anymore in future!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter#overview

*NOTE: - EARLY WARNING: Please observe that VSIX test adapters will be deprecated in the upcoming Visual Studio 2019. Please add the nuget adapter package to your solutions instead. See further information here and here*